# Compiling in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io

I have a program i am trying to compile on GCC, though this error appears:
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream >::open(std::string&)’

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    int column, row, total, counter;
    column = 1;
    row = 1;


    cout << "x-dimensions of array: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "y-dimensions of array: ";
    cin >> column;
    total = row*column;
    double myArray[row][column];
    double *myPtr;
    myPtr = *myArray;



    string input;
    cout << "Enter text file name: ";
    cin >> input;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(input);

    //Check for Error
    if (inFile.fail()){
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++){

        inFile >> *(myPtr+i);
}
```

i believe the error has to do with the infile string being used, but i declared the proper headers

Comment: why not just `std::ifstream file(input)`?

Comment: What is the command you are using to compile?

Comment: Are you using `gcc` or `g++`? This is C++ code, so the correct compiler is `g++`.

Comment: I tried compilining on g++ as well, and I recieved the same error. The command I am using is g++ projectname.cpp -o test.out

Answer (score 2):

Prior to C++11 you needed to pass a C style string to `std::ifstream::open`.  You can get a C style string from a C++ string using the `std::string::c_str` function, consider using `inFile.open(input.c_str())`.  However, if you are using C++11 this shouldn't matter.

You may also be getting an error about not declaring the function `exit`, you might want to add `#include <cstdlib>` with the other includes at the top of your file, otherwise consider just using `return 1` in this instance.

You also need to make sure you are using the C++ compiler from the GCC compiler collection, typically you would use something like `g++ input.cpp -o output` or `g++ --std=c++11 input.cpp -o output` to enable C++11.

Comment: @KeillЯandor ??  In C++11 you can use a string but otherwise you need a `char*`.

Comment: @KeillЯandor I had a typo a few seconds ago, if you comment was before my edit I understand, but otherwise I don't see what's wrong?

Comment: @nos my comment was referred to the answer "You could try using inFile.open(input.c_str())", before the edit. It wasn't accurate according to the standard, was it? I ended upvoting, but the edit was necessary.